# How to receive array from dynamic input in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to receive an array from dynamic input but `document.querySelector` is returned `undefined`

```
{chapitreList.map((partItem,index) => {
    return <div>
        <input type="text" name='soldc' id='soldc'  className ="form-control" placeholder={partItem.chapitreDepense} />
    </div>
}

const show_element = (e) => {     console.log(document.querySelector('#soldc')[0].value) }
```

Comment: Why would you use querySelector in react? Use ref or onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The issues

1. `document.querySelector` returns a single DOM node, not a `NodeList` (like `querySelectorAll` does.
2. In HTML you cannot have multiple nodes with the same ID
3. In React, avoid using native DOM calls (document.querySelector, etc.)

## The solution

Instead of using imperative methods of retrieving multiple input values, use a declarative state to hold your inputs and update the state on change.

```js
function App() {
  const chapitreList = [{ chapitreDepense: "1" }, { chapitreDepense: "2" }];
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(Array(chapitreList.length).fill(""));

  console.log(formData); // access your array

  return (
    <>
      {chapitreList.map((partItem, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            onChange={(e) =>
              setFormData((prev) => {
                prev[index] = e.target.value;
                return [...prev];
              })
            }
            type="text"
            name="soldc"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={partItem.chapitreDepense}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Read more about [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)